# Use the Start Screen instead of the Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10

Before the official release of Windows 10 there seems to have been an option (on the "Taskbar and start menu properties" navigation tab) to **un**check `When I sign in or close all apps on a screen, go to the desktop instead of Start` in order to use the Start Screen "instead" of the desktop.

Is there any way to do that in Windows 10 today?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like tablet mode: http://superuser.com/questions/947884/how-can-i-get-the-windows-8-start-screen-in-windows-10

Comment: @MC10 Thanks. You can convert your comment into an answer. Your comment was before the current answer. Unfortunately, Tablet Mode has limitations. But it looks like that's the only answer to my question.

Comment: It's fine. You can choose the upvote/select that answer. This question may be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Open the settings App, go to System->Tablet Mode and under "When I sign in" select "Automatically switch to tablet mode".](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3755-tablet-mode-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)

[image]

Now windows boots to the fullscreen Start menu which his similar to Windows 8.1.